# How to open up traffic for ip protocol ESP via iptables?

Tags: debian, iptables, nftables

I have been researching and wasn't able to find a definitive answer to the equivalent of below:

```
apt install nftables
nft add rule inet filter input ip protocol esp counter accept
```

in iptables?

Is it as simple as doing this below or is there more to it?

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally your command : `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT` is supposed to work. With this rule you accept all esp connections

and `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT` can egally work

You can find a list of supported protocols in : /etc/protocols